# NSNotificationCenter with arguments

Tags: ios4, nsnotifications, nsnotificationcenter

I am implementing an Audio based application. In that I am playing two different sounds using two AVPlayers. I need to do different actions once the sounds played. For this I used NSNotifications. But my problem is I am not able to find the Notifications related to which player. My notifications code and selector code is as follows please any one suggest me what the mistake I did.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playingItemDidEnd:)
                                             name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                           object:iPodPlayer]; 


[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                       selector:@selector(playingItemDidEnd:)
                                             name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                           object:applicationPlayer ];

- (void)playingItemDidEnd:(NSNotification *)notification 
{
      id object= [notification object];

     if(object==ipodPlayer)
     {
       printf("\n Notification from iPod Player ");

     }
     else if(object==applicationPlayer)
     {
       printf("\n Notification from application Player ");
     }
```

}

Thanks in advance,
Chandra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I need to change the code base as follows,

```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playingItemDidEnd:)
                                             name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                           object:[applicationPlayer currentItem] ];

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playingItemDidEnd:)
                                             name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                           object:[iPodPlayer currentItem]];
```

And selector code should be as follows,

```
- (void)playingItemDidEnd:(NSNotification *)notification 
{

    AVPlayerItem* object= [notification object];
    if(object==[applicationPlayer currentItem])
    {

    }
    else if(object==[avPlayer currentItem])
    {

    }
}
```